# Why are diffusion equations typically formulated using $-\partial_{x}(D\partial_{x}u)$ when Fokker--Planck has $-\partial_{xx}^{2}(Du)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, markov-process

Is there any physical process that naturally gives rise to equations of the form
$$
\partial_{t}u -\partial_{x}(D\partial_{x}u)
$$
or is this form really used in all my textbooks (e.g. Evans) and lecture notes simply because it lends itself more easily to partial integration than the Fokker-Planck form
$$
\partial_{t}u - \partial_{xx}^{2}(Du)\quad ?
$$
I have found the [Wikipedia article on anisotropic diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_diffusion) using the first form, but that just adds to my confusion because I would have thought that anisotropic diffusion, as any diffusion, would surely have to be in Fokker-Planck form. To cap it all, trying to get an intuitive idea of the two equations, I noticed that my understanding of diffusion actually matches more with the first form rather than the Fokker-Planck equation that is supposed to describe the resulting densities: effective flow equals gradient times conductivity factor, resulting changes equal divergence of flow.

Comment: Usually, the first form implies the diffusion coefficient $D$ is constant. [It also shows explicitly what the conserved quantity is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_law). The second form implies the diffusion coefficient is non constant i.e $D = D(x,t)$.

Comment: @Mattos But $u$ is the conserved quantity in both cases, and that's quite obvious, isn't it?

Comment: The first one says $Du_{x}$ is a conserved quantity.

Comment: @Cize Applying Fick's law for heat dissipation in inhomogenuous environments gives the first formulation. However, there is evidence that the physical process is actually better described by the Fokker-Planck equation http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/26/5/023/meta . As a mathematician you needn't worry too much about this though: Converting between the two introduces only a first order derivative term, so most results transfer (though not all, if you're working with nonsmooth coefficients).

Comment: For a similar question, without very satisfying answers, check https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/357033/what-is-the-proper-way-to-model-diffusion-in-inhomogeneous-media-fokker-planck

Comment: Another reference is http://matematica.univaq.it/~gabriell/4uyt59concorsi/accg-diffusione.pdf